# Error (Data mining): No cases were specified in the mining model

Tags: sql-server-2012, mdx, data-mining

Having Processed Mining structures, models and predictions before using SSDT I am attempting to perform the same operations using MDX in the hope of being able to automate some processes.

Right now I'm running into a problem when trying to insert data into my models.

```
INSERT INTO MINING STRUCTURE DumpForecasting_MIXED_Structure
(
   [TimeIndex],
   [DumpLocation_Id]
)
OPENQUERY 
(
[Data Analytics Test],
'SELECT [TimeIndex],
        [DumpLocation_Id],
        [TotalDumpCount]
FROM dbo.DailyDumpStatistics
ORDER BY [DumpLocation_Id],[TimeIndex]'
)
```

When trying to execute the above I am greeted with the error:

```
Error (Data mining): No cases were specified in  the mining model, Forecasting_ARIMA.
```

For clarification here are my creation queries:

```
CREATE MINING MODEL [DumpForecasting_MIXED]
(
[TimeIndex] date KEY TIME,
[DumpLocation_Id] long KEY,
[TotalDumpCount] long Continuous Predict
)
USING Microsoft_Time_Series(
                        AUTO_DETECT_PERIODICITY = 0.8,
                        FORECAST_METHOD = 'MIXED',
                        PREDICTION_SMOOTHING = 0.3
                        )
WITH DRILLTHROUGH
```

Followed ARIMA:

```
ALTER MINING STRUCTURE DumpForecasting_MIXED_Structure
ADD MINING MODEL Forecasting_ARIMA
(
    [TimeIndex],
    [DumpLocation_Id],      
    [TotalDumpCount] PREDICT

)
USING Microsoft_Time_Series(
                        AUTO_DETECT_PERIODICITY = 0.8,
                        FORECAST_METHOD = 'ARIMA'
                        )
WITH DRILLTHROUGH
```

and ARTXP:

```
ALTER MINING STRUCTURE DumpForecasting_MIXED_Structure
ADD MINING MODEL Forecasting_ARTXP
(
    [TimeIndex],
    [DumpLocation_Id],      
    [TotalDumpCount] PREDICT

)
USING Microsoft_Time_Series(
                        AUTO_DETECT_PERIODICITY = 0.8,
                        FORECAST_METHOD = 'ARTXP'
                        )
WITH DRILLTHROUGH
```

I can provide more details upon request. As of right now I have searched extensively but I cannot find any good sources that could help me figure this out. Suggestions and ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the mistake I had made was forgetting to add the prediction column to my insert statement.
Without it the model will only be provide with keys and no values to predict.

```
[DumpLocation_id]
```

should have been followed by:

```
,[TotalDumpCount]
```